# Create custom Conv Filter for each stride based on pixel data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

et's imagine that we have a 3x3 pixel environment. Let's build a local descriptor called the local binary pattern (LBP):

> 10 20 30
>
> 05 15 07
>
> 13 25 02

The central pixel has a value of 15. Then, if any pixel in its neighborhood, strictly defined as its immediate neighbors, is larger, we replace it with 1, and if it's smaller, with 0. We get:

> 0 1 1
>
> 0 x 0
>
> 1 1 0

Starting from the top-left corner, we have: 0 * 1 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 4 + 0 * 8 + 0 * 16 + 1 * 32 + 1 * 64 + 0 * 128 = 102. This is the new value of this pixel (x) - obtained based on its neighborhood.

How to create custom Layer based on Conv2D layer but using the dynamic and custom filter generated this way. I think it should be located in the `__call()__` metod as the filter will change every `stride`.

I'm thinking something like this but not sure if it will work correctly and  how to implement the `_lbp_filter_initializer`

```
import tensorflow as tf

class LBPLayer(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, **kwargs):
        super(LBPLayer, self).__init__(filters=filters,
                                       kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                       **kwargs)
        self.kernel_initializer = self._lbp_initializer()
        self.kernel = None

    def _lbp_filter_initializer(self, filter_shape):
      return tf.keras.initializers.???

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(LBPLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        if self.kernel is None:
          filter_shape = (*self.kernel_size, inputs.shape[-1], self.filters)
          self.initializer = _lbp_filter_initializer(filter_shape)

        center = tf.gather(inputs, [inputs.shape[1] // 2], axis=1)
        center = tf.gather(center, [inputs.shape[2] // 2], axis=2)
        center = tf.squeeze(center)

        values = tf.cast(inputs > center, tf.int32)
        values = tf.reshape(values, [-1, self.kernel_size[0] * self.kernel_size[1]])

        center_idx = tf.size(values) // 2
        values = tf.concat([values[:, :center_idx], values[:, center_idx+1:]], axis=1)

        powers = tf.pow(2, tf.range(tf.size(values[0]), dtype=tf.float32))
        result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(values, tf.float32) * powers, axis=1)

        result = tf.reshape(result, [-1, inputs.shape[1] - self.kernel_size[0] + 1,
                                     inputs.shape[2] - self.kernel_size[1] + 1,
                                     self.filters])

        return result

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        output_shape = super(LBPLayer, self).compute_output_shape(input_shape)
        return output_shape
```